# How to detect Headphone plug-In/plug-Out using C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, audio

I am working with an sound application on Ubuntu Linux where I have to make decision based on Headphone Plug In or Plug out.

How can I implement this functionality using C/C++?

What library I have to use to detect Headphone is connected or not?

Comment: Check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25776/detecting-headphone-connection-disconnection-in-linux

Comment: I already checked it , accepted answer talk about acpi_listen command line utility but here I have to perform using c/c++@solarflare

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23508/how-to-automatically-change-volume-level-when-un-plugging-headphones   The sample code given in this website works for me @thanks everyone